# C# Programmatically make enum

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I'd like ask is there any method to make enum with string array.

for example, usually we make enum like this.

```
public enum Temp {
    aa = 0,
    bb,
    cc,
    dd
}
```

What I wish to know is, how to convert String array to enum programmatically.

```
String[] Temp = { aa, bb, cc, dd }
```

to above one ( String[] to enum ).

is it possible?

if then, how can I do this?

Comment: Please be very specific, Do you want to convert a string array to an `enum` array. or do you want create a new `enum` based on a string array? In the case of the later, it doesnt make any sense what-so-ever. how would you even write further code for it. What i am guessing you want, is maybe a `Dictionary<string,int>`

Comment: You can’t create an enum programmatically because an enum is created at compile time and your program doesn’t run until run time.

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . **Why** do you want to do this?

Comment: `Dictionary<string,int>` most likely, depending on your needs, example usage `var myInt = myDict["aa"]` or `if(someValue == myDict[someKeyFormArray])` ect ect

Comment: Yes you can programmatically do this. You will have to look into System.CodDom theres a bunch of material that has to be covered so I didn't write a answer to the question.

Comment: Let me word my question differently @Arphile. Once you solve this problem, what is **next**? How are you going to **use** this `enum`?

Comment: mjwills : this is just a question which I always think about programming. Next is not now, but maybe I think I'll use this someday. I can say I just post the question because of improving my knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would be curious what you would want to do with this, but you can create a new enum type at runtime.

```
    private static Type BuildEnum(string[] enumValues, string enumName)
    {
        AssemblyName aName = new AssemblyName("TempAssembly");
        AssemblyBuilder ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
            aName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

        var eb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(aName.Name, aName.Name + ".dll").DefineEnum(enumName, TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(int));

        for (int i = 0; i < enumValues.Length; i++)
        {
            eb.DefineLiteral(enumValues[i], i);
        }
        return eb.CreateType();
    }

 var myEnum = BuildEnum(new string[] { "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd" }, "Temp");
 var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(myEnum)
```

Comment: This is clever, but I don't understand the value of doing this at run-time in the first place. I'd like the OP to explain why this is important to them.